# Merge list of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a list of dataframe in R like :

```
w = list(structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), val = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), val = 101:104), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

I would like to merge those dataframe by `var`. trying :

```
Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "var", all.x = T),w)

  var val.x val.y
1   A     1   101
2   A     1   104
3   A     2   101
4   A     2   104
5   B     3   102
6   C     4   103
```

But this is not what I'm looking for !
I would like to have the outcome as :

```
 var val val.x
  A   1   101
  A   2   104
  B   3   102
  C   4   103
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a seperate `id` column in each list and then `merge` them together.

```
Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = c("var", "id"), all.x = TRUE),
   lapply(w, function(x) transform(x, id = ave(val, var, FUN = seq_along))))


#  var id val.x val.y
#1   A  1     1   101
#2   A  2     2   104
#3   B  1     3   102
#4   C  1     4   103
```

---

In `tidyverse` the same logic can be applied using :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(w, ~.x %>% group_by(var) %>% mutate(id = row_number())) %>%
    reduce(left_join, by = c("var", "id"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly joining by the row id within each group. It would make things easier to make that an explicit variable.

An easy way to create that variable is `data.table::rowid()`:

```
w <- lapply(w, function(x) {x$id <- data.table::rowid(x$var); x})
Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = c("var", "id"), all.x = T), w)
  var id val.x val.y
1   A  1     1   101
2   A  2     2   104
3   B  1     3   102
4   C  1     4   103
```